# Python Check Value for String

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find if any form of the words "Next Steps" (upper or lowercase) do NOT exist in my values

Here is my code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'xml')
updates = soup.findAll('body')
for update in updates:
    if not "Next Steps" in update:
        print (update)
    else:
        print "update good"
```

and here is what the values look like I am trying to search through:

```
<body>This is sentence one</body>
<body>This is sentence two. Next Steps: Find sentence three.</body>
<body>This is sentence three.

Next Steps:
Find sentence four.</body>
```

Right now it returns every value in "update", whether it contains the "Next Steps" or not.

Comment: Did you try `if not "Next Steps" in update.text`? Or mayve `.value`, I forgot which one points to the string inside the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`soup.findAll` doesn't return a list of strings. That's why `updates` looks like:

```
<body>This is sentence one</body>
```

and not

```
This is sentence one
```

You can get the text with with the `text` attribute.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'xml')
updates = soup.findAll('body')
for update in updates:
    if "next steps" not in update.text.lower():
        print (update)
    else:
        print("update good")
```